# helm given random name replace by another

Tags: kubernetes-helm

When I install a package with helm, I have a random name as you can see below. 
 How to change it or how to give your specific name ?

```
vetoed-kiwi             1               Tue Aug 14 11:02:20 2018        DEPLOYED        karaf-0.0.1     default  
wobbling-echidna        1               Tue Aug 14 11:00:03 2018        FAILED          karaf-0.0.1     default
```

I try to change the given name like (vetoed-kiwi) by a specific name of my choosing.  Do you know how I can do it ?

Comment: Please edit your question like shown below. ([also join here](https://english.stackexchange.com/)).
Hi folks,
when I installed a package with helm, I've a random name as you can see below. I searched on internet but didn't find anything about how to change it or give it specific name.
I tried to change the given name (like vetoed-kiwi) by a specific name which I would give. Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: Note: I am not being rude. Actually, I have reached my editing limit. So, I am telling you to edit yourself. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`helm install`](https://docs.helm.sh/helm/#helm-install) takes a `--name` option.  See also the ["Using Helm"](https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/#using-helm) section of the docs.